# Any way to specify absolute paths in FTP URLs?

Tags: java, url, ftp

I'm using the Java URL and URLConnection classes to upload an file to a server using FTP. I don't need to do anything other than simply upload the file, so I'd like to avoid any external libraries and I'm wary of using the non-supported sun.net.ftp class.

Is there any way to use absolute paths in the FTP connection string? I'd like to put my files in something like "/ftptransfers/..." but the FTP path is relative to the user home directory.

Sample upload code:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://username:password@host/file.txt");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream out = uc.getOutputStream() ;
out.write("THIS DATA WILL BE WRITTEN TO FILE".getBytes());
out.close();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did actually find out there is a semi-standard way to do it that worked for me.

Short answer: **replace the leading slash with "%2F"**

Long answer: per the ["A FTP URL Format"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-casey-url-ftp-00) document:

> For example, the URL "ftp://myname@host.dom/%2Fetc/motd" is
> interpreted by FTP-ing to "host.dom", logging in as "myname"
> (prompting for a password if it is asked for), and then executing
> "CWD /etc" and then "RETR motd".

> This has a different meaning from
> "ftp://myname@host.dom/etc/motd" which would "CWD etc" and then
> "RETR motd"; the initial "CWD" might be executed relative to the
> default directory for "myname".

> On the other hand,
> "ftp://myname@host.dom//etc/motd", would "CWD " with a null
> argument, then "CWD etc", and then "RETR motd".

Comment: even though it sounds more like exploiting than standard procedure, I did find this a really useful solution! I didn't want to use any external libs as well, nor sun.net.ftp directly. And apache commons FTPClient does not support proxies (besides system properties) and it is an external lib. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Actually, this is standart way. It follows RFC 1738 (http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1738/) which is not yet obsoleted in part of FTP URL scheme

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to use the apache commons FTP component, and do a 'cd' after you make the connection.

you can always write a wrapper so that the URL can be specified in the format above if you so wish.

-ace

Comment: as much as the OP doesn't want to use an external library, I think this is a case where it's called for (unless he wants to implement the cd command himself, which I guess he could do)