# How to download/read html file via ftp url?

Tags: java, url, ftp, download

I am having trouble getting the html text from this html file via ftp. I use beautiful soup to read an html file via http/https but for some reason I cannot download/read from an ftp. Please help!

Here is the url.
[a link](ftp://ftp.legis.state.tx.us/bills/832/billtext/html/house_resolutions/HR00001_HR00099/HR00014I.htm)

Here is my code so far.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
String total = "";
String line;
ur = "ftp://ftp.legis.state.tx.us/bills/832/billtext/html/house_resolutions/HR00001_HR00099/HR00014I.htm"
try {
    URL url = new URL(ur);
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream(); // To download
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            total += reader.readLine();

} finally {
    if (reader != null) 
        try { reader.close(); 
        } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

This code working for me, Java 1.7.0_25. Notice that you were storing one of every two lines, calling `reader.readLine()` both in the condition and in the body of the while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String total = "";
    String line;
    String ur = "ftp://ftp.legis.state.tx.us/bills/832/billtext/html/house_resolutions/HR00001_HR00099/HR00014I.htm";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(ur);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream(); // To download
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total += line;
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thought this is related to a wrong path resolution as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162053/any-way-to-specify-absolute-paths-in-ftp-urls) but this does not help.

I don't know what is exactly going wrong here but I can only reproduce this error on this ftp-server and with the MacOS Java 1.6.0_33-b03-424. I can't reproduce it with Java 1.7.0_25. So perhaps you check for a Java update.

Or you could use [commons FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) to retrieve the file:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("ftp.legis.state.tx.us");
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
client.login("anonymous", "");
client.changeWorkingDirectory("bills/832/billtext/html/house_resolutions/HR00001_HR00099");
InputStream is = client.retrieveFileStream("HR00014I.htm");
```